# ElasticSearch Percolator API with queries that run against child documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch

According to the elasticsearch official documentation of percolator API in

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html

```
Because the percolator API is processing one document at a time, it doesn’t support queries and filters that run against child documents such as has_child, has_parent and top_children.
```

In my application i am using the percolator API on a type with no parent/child relationship and it works perfectly.

Now I want to combine this type with another type having a parent/child relationship with the first one. Obviously it doesn't work because the percolator API can not parse the query when it detects has_child, has_parent or top_children.

I was looking for a solution to use the percolator without changing the mapping of my index but I couldn't find an appropriate one.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since percolator will not work on parent/child relation until few month ( percolator on nested just wait out), I think the bestsolution is that you change the implementation of your software and use nested object instead of parent/child.

I know it might sound heavy cause it will probably involve lot of change but it may be the best solution.

Sincerely;